# Angular shows numbers with extra zero

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to show sum of two numbers but it return with extra zero.

## Sample

```
newprice -> 174.000
added number -> 1
total should be -> 174.001

but it shows 1.740.001
```

## Code

`view`

```
{{(newprice + optionPrice | currency: 'Rp ' : 'symbol' : '1.0-0')}}
```

`controller`

```
export class OptionsPage implements OnInit {
  optionPrice = '0';
  newprice: null;

  constructor(
    public modalController: ModalController
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.newprice; // it comes from other page in this case is (174000)
    this.optionPrice;
  }

// this price comes from selected option and will be sum to "newprice" value (in this sample is 1)
  onChange(value) {
    console.log(value);
    this.optionPrice = value;
  }
}
```

**Any idea?**

Comment: Why are you accessing the variables that you've defined in your component in the `OnInit` hook without even doing anything to the variables?

Comment: it's modal i need values as soon as modal pops up that's why

Comment: And I'm pretty sure that's not how you add two integers together, unless you've specified the unit for both integers. (In this case, I think you're intending to add cents to dollars - please check your logic before posting)

Comment: But you're not actually logging the values of the variables to the console or anything.

Comment: @Edric dude, currently i have no issue with getting 2 values that i need my issue is returning it as true amount. any idea on that?

Comment: Also just curious, but why are you storing the value of the prices as a string type instead of a float/integer type?

Comment: prices are returning from server api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it acts like `newprice` and `optionPrice` are strings.

You can do it like:

```
{{((+newprice) + (+optionPrice) | currency: 'Rp ' : 'symbol' : '1.0-0')}}
//  ^             ^    this "+" operators converts strings to number
```

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: No worries, please.